# Subgit migrate newer Svn revisions to existing Gitlab Project

Tags: svn, gitlab, subgit

My co-worker has previous migrated "project A" from Svn to Gitlab, and numerous other projects use "project A" as submodule.

However, since last migration, some changes have been made in "project A" in Svn, and now I am trying to migrate those newer changes from Svn to the exist Gitlab project that my co-worker created last time.

I can not simply re-migrate the entire "project A" because doing so would change the commit hash, thus "project A" can no longer be a submodule unless I change all other projects.

Is this possible with subgit?
I tried
**subgit import --minimal-revision revision_number --svn-url** which would allow me to copy a specific revision in svn for "project A" but I do not know how I would add this to my existing gitlab project?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import only one (or a very few) specific revision(s) from SVN to GitLab, you could simply:

- clone the GitLab repository
- clone (with SVN directly, no subgit involved) the SVN repository and make sure it reflects the revision you want to import
- import one revision into the local Git repository

Set the [right author/email](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing)

```bash
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=<the Author name from SVN revision>
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=<the Author email from SVN revision>
```

Import:

```bash
cd /path/to/local/Git/repository
# make sure your .gitignore includes `.svn/`
git --work-tree=/path/to/local/SVN/repository add .
git commit -m "Import revision"
# if you are done
unset GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
unset GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do with SubGit as well, in the way you mentioned: first, import revisions that you need in a partial new repository using SubGit's `minimalRevision` setting to not to import the whole repo; then fetch needed branch to the "project A", like

```
git fetch <Partial repo path> refs/heads/master:refs/new_revs/trunk
```

and then manually merge the changes in the project A repository.